# When running a google app script on a google sheets, does it run one app script file, or can it run more than one file?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, runtime

My plan is to link a google app script to my google sheets. I have 16 tabs on my google sheets. I want to make 16 app script files inside the same app script project. I also want to set time trigger on each app script to run at a certain time. My question is will every file inside the app script file will run, or only one app script will run?

The output I am looking for is that I do not have to press any button on the sheets or the app script. I want it to run each app script file at a certain time, and for the google sheets to update at that time. Each google sheet tab should update at the time they are assigned in the app script. How can I make this happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Every scripts are runnable, unless the function names do not duplicate.

A `project` is similar to a html file, while each `script file` is included by `<script src="name.js">`

---

However, I doubt whether you really need one script file, or even a function for each sheet.

Of course, it depends on what you want to do. But I guess the works are similar and they could be combined into one or a few functions.